# Is there a closed formula for the sum of a geometric progression with binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, geometric-progressions

The title asks it all.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}x^{i+1}=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial theorem gives 
$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom n i x^i.$$
So your sum in question is simply $x(1+x)^n$.